# HOw to implement AJAX session timeout redirect in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout, action-filter

In my MVC application, implement session time out redirect functionality.

Now, all the requests are done through AJAX so, on AJAX request, it should redirect to session timeout page if time out is reached.

I tried several approach from net but it did now work out.

I am not using - [AUTHROIZE] attribute for security. just using custom login authentication.

Tried below approach but not work out. It did not reach to the attribute.

Problem is, URL gets appended with "RetrunURL" paramter and not work out.

```
                      /// <summary>
        /// Extend AuthorizeAttribute to correctly handle AJAX authorization
        /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    Error = “NotAuthorized”,
                    LogOnUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
          // this is a standard request, let parent filter to handle it
           base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}

 Now, we need to modify our client sciptt to handle 401 response code:
 getData = function(request) {
$.ajax({
    url: “/home/GetData”,
    type: “POST”,
    data: request,
    contentType: “application/json;”,
    dataType: “json”,
    success: function (repJSON) {
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.status === 401) {
            window.location.href=xhr.Data.LogOnUrl;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

pLease guide how to resolve this.